# How to control coloums element toggle on\off in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, html

I have the requirement where i have to make bottom td element available if *Is This mercer case* yes.And if Not it should be invisible.

```
<table>                     
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Is this a Mercer case?</span> 

        </th>
        <td>
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!mercerVal}" multiselect="false">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!mercerOptions}" /> 
            </apex:selectList>
        </td>
        <th>
            <span>Direct Deposit of Cliam Reimbursement</span> 

        </th>
        <td>
            <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!costContainmentVendorValList}" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!costContainmentVendorOptions}" />
            </apex:selectCheckboxes>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant markup for these two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of explanation, when you rerender an element, you only actually change the DOM of its children, so you need to wrap your `selectCheckboxes` in an outer element that, when rerendered, will update the rendered property of the tag itself.

You can modify the `selectList` and `selectOptions` as follows:

```
<apex:selectList ...>
    <apex:selectOptions />
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="deposit" />
</apex:selectList>
...
<apex:outputPanel id="deposit">
    <apex:selectCheckboxes rendered="{!mercerVal == 'Yes'}" ...>
        ...
    </apex:selectCheckboxes>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrain.I was wondering these both are same panel already.Its like They are part of same Row of table.Would panel makes it toggle as coloum.Would that effect will be there.

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, but which element you rerender is not super important, as long as it is wraps the `selectCheckboxes` at some level.

Comment: Ok,Please also guide me how can i see what value is comming in !mercerVal..Do i print in debug log for controller or any other simpler option.